# Making a Sukka under some shutters on an exterior wall

Tags: sukkah

The shutters aren't open at night. The Sukka is built in such a way as the shutters above it are exactly above only one corner. The shutters are two, of wood and open outward from the window above extending about a meter if they aren't fastened back against the wall. Usually these shutters are either fastened back when opened or they are closed, but sometimes they are left open at an angle and then they probably extend at about half a meter outward over the Sukka. 
So, is that whole corner not a good place to eat? or is it just to be avoided when the shutters are extended over the corner one meter or one half meter depending on how the shutters are opened? And is it a good place to sit and eat at night when the shutters are completly closed up?

Comment: (1) You seem to be asking a personal question. For that you need a Rav. Or you can edit the question into asking what dinim and sources are involved in this question. (2) The details of your question are not totally clear. I suggest you include a drawing. The shutters are presumably vertical? of some thickness? what are the dimensions of the sukkah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the "uncovered" part of the Sukka is still 7-Tefachim by 7-Tefachim (28 inches x 28 inches) when the shutters are open, the Sukka is Kosher when they are open.

However, when they are open, if you sit under them you are not sitting in a Sukka.

So make sure that you don't sit on that side, and then you don;t have to worry if the shutters are open or closed.

If the shutters would extend more than 4 Amos (~2 meters) then - when the shutters are open - that side would not be counted as a wall, and you'd need 3 other Kosher walls for the Sukka to be Kosher.

All this assumes that the shutter - when open - creates a roof over the Shukka - [image: i.e. they open like this <code>^</code>] - but if they are simply doors that swing over the Sukka, [image: shutter opening outwards] then they can be ignored.

However, if the doors would be wider than 4 Tefachim (16 inches) (e.g. they fold up  [image: shutters folded up]) then you couldn't sit under them.

Source: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [סימן קלד - הלכות סכה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0133_L2)

> **סעיף ו'** 
>   בַּסֻּכּוֹת הַבְּנוּיוֹת, לִפְעָמִים בּוֹלְטִים דַפִּים לְמַעְלָה עַל הַכְּתָלִים, וְעַל דַּפִּים אֵלּו מֻנָּחִים הַכְּלוֹנְסָאוֹת שֶׁעֲלֵיהֶם הַסְּכָךְ. וּמֵאַחַר שֶׁאֵין הַדַּף רָחָב אַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת, אֵנוֹ פוסֵל אֶת הַסֻּכָּה מִשׁוּם סְכָךְ פָּסוּל, כִּי הֲלָכָה לְמשֶׁה מִסִּינַי הִיא, דִבְפָחוֹת מֵאַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת, אָמְרֵינָן דֹּפֶן עֲקֻמָּה. פֵּרוּשׁ, שֶנֶּחְשָׁב אֶל הַדֹּפֶן, וְחָשְבֵינָן לֵהּ כְּאִלּוּ הַדֹּפֶן נִתְעַקְּמָה שָׁם לְמַעְלָה, אֶלָּא שֶׁאֵין יושְׁבִים וְאֵין יְשֵׁנִים שָׁם תַּחַת הַדַּף, כִּי שָׁם אֵין לוֹ דִין סֻכָּה, וַאֲפִלּוּ אֵינוֹ רָחָב אֶלָּא אַרְבָּעָה טְפָחִים. אֲבָל יֶתֶר הַסֻּכָּה, כְּשֵׁרָה. אַךְ אִם מֻנָּחִים אֵצֶל הַדֹּפֶן דַּפִּים בְּרֹחַב אַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת אוֹ יוֹתֵר, זֶהוֹ נִקְרָא סְכָךְ פָּסוּל, וּפוֹסֵל אֶת כָּל הַסֻּכָּה. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם אִם אֵינוֹ כֵן אֶלָּא בְּצַד אֶחָד, כְּמוֹ שֶהַדֶּרֶךְ הוּא בִּקְצָת סֻכּוֹת בְּנוּיוֹת שֶׁעושִׁין קְצָת תִּקְרָה מִצַּד אֶחָד (כְּדֵי לְפַנּוֹת לְשָׁם אֶת הַכֵּלִים תֵּכֶף בְּהַתְחָלַת הַגְשָׁמִים), זֶה אֵינוֹ מַזִּיק, דְכֵיוָן שֶׁאֵינוֹ אֶלָּא מִצַּד אֶחָד, הֲרֵי יֵשׁ כָּאן עוֹד שָׁלֹשׁ דְּפָנוֹת כְּשֵׁרוֹת שֶׁמֻנָּח עֲלֵיהֶן סְכָךְ כָּשֵׁר, וְסֻכָּה מִשָׁלֹשׁ דְּפָנוֹת גַּם כֵּן כְּשֵׁרָה, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁיְהֵא שָׁם שִׁעוּר סֻכָּה, דְּהַיְנוּ לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת שִׁבְעָה טְפָחִים עַל שִׁבְעָה טְפָחִים בִּמְרֻבָּע, וְלֹא יֵשְׁבוּ תַּחַת הַתִּקְרָה. ‏

Comment: This answered my question, the shutters are like the second photograph.